# Comparing GLKMatrix4

Tags: glkit

How would you normally compare two GLKMatrix4, or at least check if on is the identity matrix?

A cursory search of GLKMatrix4.h shows no util function, and I was feeling silly checking every field manually like this:

```
static BOOL GLKMatrix4EqualToMatrix4(GLKMatrix4 a, GLKMatrix4 b)
{
  return
  a.m00 == b.m00 &&
  a.m01 == b.m01 &&
  a.m02 == b.m02 &&
  a.m03 == b.m03 &&
  a.m10 == b.m10 &&
  a.m11 == b.m11 &&
  a.m12 == b.m12 &&
  a.m13 == b.m13 &&
  a.m20 == b.m20 &&
  a.m21 == b.m21 &&
  a.m22 == b.m22 &&
  a.m23 == b.m23 &&
  a.m30 == b.m30 &&
  a.m31 == b.m31 &&
  a.m32 == b.m32 &&
  a.m33 == b.m33;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform it into string and then compare using this function NSStringFromGLKMatrix4

Comment: Clever, but ugh ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
static BOOL GLKMatrix4EqualToMatrix4(GLKMatrix4 a, GLKMatrix4 b) {
    return memcmp(a.m, b.m, sizeof(a.m)) == 0;
}
```

Because **memcmp** is usually highly optimized for specific architectures, it should be the fastest, and cleanest approach.

See [Why is memcmp so much faster than a for loop check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106801/why-is-memcmp-so-much-faster-than-a-for-loop-check) for discussion on **memcmp**.