# How are two strings compared?

Tags: c++, string

I am not sure how to form this question, since english isn't my primary language. . .

What is the process behind comparing two strings?

For example, how does a computer, on which logic, compare two strings?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s1 {"b"};
    std::string s2 {"abc"};

    if(s1 > s2)
    {
        std::cout << s1 << " > " << s2;
    }
    else std::cout << s2 << " > " << s1;

    return 0;
}
```

ouput: `b > abc`

How does a computer come up with this logic (even though it is correct).

I imagined computers logic to be converting chars into integers then comparing them by size, which is not the case here since if it was

`b > abc` would be treated like `98 > 97 + 98 + 99` which is incorrect.

Comment: `98 > 97`, that's it. Why would you add up the ASCII codes of the letters anyway?

Comment: The computer doesn't need to convert characters into integers - characters are already integer values

Comment: It compares the first pair of different characters. One that is larger belongs to a "larger" string.

Comment: On a side note, your `else` branch is wrong. If s1 is not greater than s2, it may also be that s1 is equal to s2.

Comment: When you say "a computer", this sounds like the CPU itself performed the comparison. That's a wrong picture. The lexicographical comparison performed for `std::string` is an operation on a much higher abstraction level.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. @zett42 I see now that my else branch is wrong. That doesn't interfere with the question though... Also @Christian Hackl my english vocabulary isn't very good. I meant more like compiler, or whatever does the comparison :) @ForceBru I just tested if I put one string as `b` and one as `bcd` and replaced the whole if with `if(s1 == s2) std::cout << "s1 = s2";` it wouldn't enter it. So it  doesn't compare only first letters.

Comment: [Here is a nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21106815/7571258) about how a string comparison might look like at the low level (assembly language), which is "what the computer comes up with".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison logic is specified by the string's char traits, which for `std::string` is [`std::char_traits<char>::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/compare), which in turn specifies "lexicographic comparison". Each character is compared based on its numeric value, which is given by the encoding of the execution character set. On your platform, `'b' > 'a'` is true, so `s2` compares less than `s1`.

Comment: Where does the reference state anything about encoding and character sets being involved in string comparison?

Comment: @zett42 it doesnt need to because the comparison only cares about the numerical value

Comment: Just checked, the `std::char_traits<char>::compare()` implementation of MSVC++2017 does a simple `memcmp()`, so it doesn't really care about encodings and character sets.

Comment: @zett42: I think you're misunderstanding the point about encodings. The result of `'a'  < 'b'` depends on the numeric values of `'a'` and `'b'`, which is precisely what the "encoding" of the execution character set is. If `'a'` is 10 and `'b'` is 20, the comparison is true, and if `'a'` is 10 and `'b'` is 5, the comparison is false.

Comment: I just had to look up "execution character set", MSVC has a [pretty good explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708818.aspx): _The execution character set is the encoding used for the text of your program that is input to the compilation phase after all preprocessing steps._ ... still need to find a character set where `'a' < 'b' == false` though ;-)

Comment: @zett42: I mean, `'a'` and `'b'` are a red herring, of course. But sooner or later the OP will have strings with mixed case, or with things like `'-'` or `'_'`...