# Why does memcmp return a negative value when there is a positive difference?

Tags: c, string.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int test1 = 8410092;    // 0x8053EC
    int test2 = 8404974;    // 0x803FEE
    char *t1 = ( char*) &test1;
    char *t2 = (char*) &test2;
    int ret2 = memcmp(t1,t2,4);

    printf("%d",ret2);

}
```

Here's a very basic function that when run prints -2. Maybe I am totally misunderstanding memcmp, but I thought if it returns the difference between the first different bytes. Since test1 is a larger num than test2, shouldn't the printed value be positive?

I am using the standard gcc.7 compiler for ubuntu.

Comment: `memcmp` compares bytes, not `int` values. So endianness is relevant.

Comment: Also `memcmp` does not specify what the magnitude of the return value means. Only `< 0` or `0` or `> 0`.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I realize the magnitude isn't important. I just don't understand why the signs aren't the same. Are you saying that it's comparing the LSB of test1 with the LSB of test2 first instead of the MSB?

Comment: As I wrote, the `int` values are irrelevant. `memcmp` compares byte by byte. It knows nothing about your `int` values. For example, suppose you passed it two arrays of two 16-bit values each. Would you expect `memcmp` to know they were, say, `short` values?

Comment: On your Ubuntu machine, the LSB of the values is stored at the lowest address, and is compared first.  Since 0xEE is larger than 0xEC, you get a negative value returned — you cannot rely on it being `-2`, only on it being less than zero.  If you were on a big-endian machine (e.g. SPARC), then you'd get different results.  You'd also get a different result if you had `int test1 = 841088;`.

Comment: Effectively you are comparing the strings "\xEC\x53\x80\x00" and "\xEE\x3F\x80\x00", because of endianness. So yeah the first one is smaller than the second.

Comment: Incidentally, you could avoid `t1` and `t2` and use: `int rc = memcmp(&test1, &test2, sizeof(test1));` — the first two arguments to `memcmp()` are of type `void *` and any object pointer (as opposed to function pointer) type converts automatically to `void *` without needing an explicit cast.

Comment: @Johnathan Leffler So this means memcmp can return different signs accross platforms for the same code? If I were on a big endian would memcmp return a positive signage?

Comment: Yes (different on different platforms) and yes (big-endian for example values would return a positive value for the shown test values).

Comment: Apologies. Is there a way I can "force" endianess for the piece of code. Like I Want it to start with comparing x00 and x00 first?

Comment: With `htonl()` I guess. This function converts whatever endinaness the system is using to "network" endinaness, which is big-endian and meet the criteria. Though it's rather silly to compare ints with `memcmp()` when the CPU can do it directly.

Comment: No, not really.  Why do you want do it?  OK; yes, you can forcibly store the value in a big-endian format and then do the `memcmp()` on that, and you will get the answer you seem to seek, but why not just use `test1 < test2` (or whatever comparison operator you're interested in).

Comment: @knowads How about just *not using `memcmp`* ? If you want to compare numerical scalars, then do so; `memcmp` doesn't so why try to hammer in a nail with a screwdriver ?

Comment: They are different. Thats all.

Comment: In the scenario that these aren't ints but just char * to the same set of chars would (<.=,>) comparitors work as well>

Comment: @knowads Yeah we realize you are performing the necessary steps to make use of `memcmp()` to compare those integers, but that's precisely the problem. `memcmp()` compares byte per byte and is not suitable to compare multi-byte scalar types because, among other reasons, the way they are structured in memory is architecture specific.

Comment: @knowads You can "force endianess" by using a character array: `uint8_t arr[4] = { 0x00, 0x80, 0x53, 0xEC};`. This will guarantee MS byte first no matter system. But you cannot use the contents of this data as a 32 bit value on a Little Endian machine, without shuffling it around first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `memcmp()` runs byte comparison. Here is a man quote

> int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
>
> RETURN VALUE:
>          The memcmp() function returns an integer less than, equal to, or
>          greater than zero if the first n bytes of s1 is found, respectively,
>          to be less than, to match, or be greater than the first n bytes of
>          s2
>          For a nonzero return value, the sign is determined by the sign of the
>          difference between the first pair of bytes (interpreted as unsigned
>          char) that differ in s1 and s2.
>          If n is zero, the return value is zero.
>   http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html

If the bytes are not the same, the sign of the difference depends on the target endianness.

One application of `memcmp()` is testing if two large arrays are the same, which could be faster than writing a loop that runs element by element comparison. Refer to this stack questions for more details. [Why is memcmp so much faster than a for loop check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106801/why-is-memcmp-so-much-faster-than-a-for-loop-check)

Answer (score 4):

`memcmp` compares memory. That is, it compares the bytes used to represent objects. The bytes used to represent objects may vary from one C implementation to another. Per C 2018 6.2.6 2:

> Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, the number,
>   order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or implementation-defined.

To compare the **values** represented by objects, use the ordinary operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, and `!=`. Comparing the **memory** of objects with `memcmp` should be used for limited purposes, such as inserting objects into a tree that only needs to be able to store and retrieve items without caring about what their values mean.