# Creation of generic less than function in C

Tags: c, generics, void-pointers

I am looking to implement something similar to

```
int memcmp ( const void * ptr1, const void * ptr2, size_t num );
```

For comparison of numerical types such as floats, doubles and integers
but with distinguishing between two case (1) < and (2) =,> rather than <between 3 cases (1)<, ==(2)==, and >(3)>. My aim is to reduce the number of the used instructions, assuming running on a standard laptop (x86 architecture).

Comment: "reduce the number of the used instructions" cannot be done since the machine instruction (`cmp`) already determines the tertiary result `<`, `<=` or `==` . Your function will actually spend additional instructions throwing away that information!

Comment: @Gaberocksall sort of yes but there is usually no machine instruction to load the value <, ==, > zero. But to OP, your optimization **only** concerns the return value which for **long** comparables is quite negligible.

Comment: But `memcmp` from lib already faster than custom implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106801/why-is-memcmp-so-much-faster-than-a-for-loop-check

Comment: Normally `memcmp` is implemented in an optimized way, or even built into the language, so your own "clever" memcmp will most likely be slower.

Comment: @Gaberocksall They aren't necessarily using x86.

Comment: updated the question to consider x86

Comment: @GideonKogan your compiler most likely take care of this. Look at the generated assembly code using `memcmp`

Comment: @Jabberwocky is it close to lt (<) performance? I can not find it? I was under the impression that generic coding should not reduce performance. Am I wrong?

Comment: @GideonKogan I don't know, look at the generated assembly code when you use `memcmp`.

Comment: The `memcmp()` function returns a value `<= 0` when the first target is `<=` the second target. There is nothing to do, no extra work.

Comment: What do you wany to compare?

Comment: Note that the result of `memcmp(&x,&y,sizeof(x)) < 0` can, and often will, be different from that of `x < y`.

Comment: What do you want to compare? Which kind of values? Question is not clear.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I would like it to accept all the numeric types

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, I have noted it. Can you explain why?

Comment: It isn't clear what kind of justification to this fact you expect. Sky is blue, water is wet, comparing numbers is different from comparing their bytes. You can look at the bytes that make up, say, 1 and -1, and decide for yourself how `memcmp` should treat them.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the problem is likely just `#define less(a,b,n) (memcmp(a,b,n) < 0)`.

There's a bunch of advantages with using `memcmp` since the compiler is likely to highly optimize the use of it. It may look at what you use as input and inline `memcmp` accordingly, giving the most efficient code.

For example `memcmp` has the requirement to cast each byte to `unsigned char` internally and work on misaligned data. But if you provide lets say two chunks of 8 byte aligned data on a x86_64, there's probably no reason for the machine code to chew through it byte by byte.

Here's an example where I hacked together a semi-naive version of a "less" function working similar to `memcmp`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool lesscmp (const void* obj1, const void* obj2, size_t size)
{
  const unsigned char* o1 = (const unsigned char*)obj1;
  const unsigned char* o2 = (const unsigned char*)obj2;

  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    if(o1[i] != o2[i])
    {
      return o1[i] < o2[i];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
  char s1[] = "This is some data";
  char s2[] = "This is some other data";

  printf("%d\n", memcmp(s1,s2,sizeof s1) < 0);
  printf("%d\n", memcmp(s2,s1,sizeof s1) < 0);
  printf("%d\n", memcmp(s1,s1,sizeof s1) < 0);
  printf("%d\n", lesscmp(s1,s2,sizeof s1));
  printf("%d\n", lesscmp(s2,s1,sizeof s1));
  printf("%d\n", lesscmp(s1,s1,sizeof s1));
}
```

When implementing it, I soon recognized the problem that although we are looking for the `<` result, we have to keep looping while the bytes are equal. And when they aren't, that's when we can start looking for `<`, with the cost of additional comparisons.

Because C has no operator working like "use <= but store the less or equal statuses separately, so we can loop based on the equal flag but return the less flag". On the assembler level we can likely do that however, making this function a good candidate for inline assembler in case we care deeply about performance. And yet unless we happen to be some x86 assembler guru, we can probably not hope to beat the compiler even with hand-crafted assembler.

Looking at the generated code (gcc -O3 x86) in Compiler Explorer, we can conclude that my home-made function is a mess:

```
lesscmp:
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L5
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     .L4
.L3:
        add     rax, 1
        cmp     rdx, rax
        je      .L5
.L4:
        movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR [rsi+rax]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rdi+rax], cl
        je      .L3
        setb    al
        ret
.L5:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

`cmp` all over the place - it has more branches than a Christmas tree! This will not perform well at all.

Whereas the equivalent `memcmp` calls are sometimes inlined, resulting in various fancy x86 intrinsics, hard-coded "magic numbers" etc and very few if any branches. Way more efficient.

As so the conclusion is that "pre-mature optimization" remains the root of all evil, and `memcmp(...) < 0` is likely the best solution for this purpose no matter the target.

Comment: he did mention what he wants to compare. Floats? integers? Structs?

Comment: @gulpr `memcmp` compares raw data no matter what meaning that data happens to hold on the higher level, so I don't see how that matters.

Comment: I know what `memcpy` does but I do not know what OP wants.

Comment: @gulpr Seems pretty clear to me, given that one knows what `memcmp` returns...

Comment: @Lundin comparing raw data is not exactly the same as comparing typed data. OP want to compare typed data, not raw byte arrays.

Comment: `lesscmp()` invokes UB if all `size` bytes are equal, so `i == size` after the loop and then you return `o1[i] < o2[i]`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Ah that's true. This was really just a quick & dirty function but I'll fix it, thanks.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Where did you read that?

Comment: @Lundin Right! from his previous question. He wanted to compare long, float, etc question was badly expressed, I suggested him to write another (that one).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I'm answering this question here, as phrased posted here...