# Trying to get fast reverse memcmp in C++

Tags: c++11, reverse, memcmp

I need to compare two char arrays as fast as possible and return which one is bigger. Normally I would use memcmp but unfortunately, there's only a pointer available for my tool pointing to the data stored in reverse order, or to the LSB in other words.
I've already read this question: [How to do reverse memcmp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406148/how-to-do-reverse-memcmp), but since it was asked in 2011 for c I was hoping that there has been some improvement since that time.
Looking at the first answer here [Why is memcmp so much faster than a for loop check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106801/why-is-memcmp-so-much-faster-than-a-for-loop-check), there should be a direction flag which would solve my problem, but I've no experience in embedding assembler code in c++ at all, so debugging or giving any support to others would be impossible for me.

Is there any builtin version of reverse memcmp which has been released since this question has been asked the first time?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider benchmarking `std::lexicographical_compare` with `std::reverse_iterator`. The compiler may be able to optimize this well enough.

Comment: I feared that this would be the answer, maybe I'll give it a try even if I still don't feel comfortable with my lack of knowledge about assembler. As I think that my tool will be used over the next few years, please feel free to give me a hint if somewhen a builtin version will be introduced. @rightføld: thank you, I'll try it.

Comment: I'm with @rightføld: For any situation where your code needs to be "as fast as possible", you need to set up some proper benchmarks which run under the same conditions as your actual program (or as close as possible). Otherwise you'll have no way to tell what implementations are faster on your platform.