# I need to copy in reverse manner an array of longs I need a system function such as memcpy is there any?

Tags: c++, c, memcpy

I need to copy from end to start an array of longs to an array of longs as is shown in the code bellow. Is there any function similar to memcpy for the required purpose ?

```
typedef long int myT;
const size_t n=5;
myT a[n];
myT b[n]={12,45,56,76,78};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    myT *p1=&a[0];
    myT *p2=&b[n];
    for(auto i=n;i-->0;) 
        *p1++=*--p2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C memcpy in reverse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242498/c-memcpy-in-reverse)

Comment: [`std::reverse_copy(b, b+n, a)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy), or since C++11 `std::reverse_copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::begin(a))`

Answer (score 2):

That's what [`std::reverse_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy) does.

```
int main()
{
  std::reverse_copy(b, b+n, a);
}
```

or since C++11:

```
int main()
{
  std::reverse_copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::begin(a));
}
```

Comment: The implementation of reverse_copy is just as the code I shown. The question is if exists an efficient implementation that is optimized !!!

Comment: Erm, that's not what you asked. You said "system function", which does not mean "efficient implementation that is optimized". Your code definitely doesn't do anything clever, using a standard library function _might be_ optimized to do something clever. So in general prefer the standard library function instead of rolling your own. For code like this you should trust the compiler to optimize it anyway.